# "Error #119: cast to type <..> is not allowed" when using armcc

Tags: c, casting, armcc

I'm trying to compile an existed project (which was designed for gcc) with armcc.
For some reason I get the #119 error for the following casting:

```
(keyCert)(pCertHeader->flags)
```

I find it very odd because the flags variable is from type uint32_t, and keyCert type is actually uint32_t.

```
typedef union { 
        struct {
                uint32_t      a:4;
                uint32_t      b:28;
        }c;
        uint32_t      d;
} keyCert;
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?
Note that I was able to compile it with gcc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find it very odd because the flags variable is from type uint32_t, and keyCert type is actually uint32_t.

Wrong, `keyCert` type is `union {...}`. Compiler doesn't know if you store `struct c` or `uint32_t d` in `keyCert`, so compiler cannot assume it is `uint32_t`. The reason GCC possibly doesn't throw any errors is because it is compiler extension. ISO C forbids this type of casting.

Even in GCC if you compile it using C99 strict mode, you will get the following message:

> warning: ISO C forbids casts to union type [-Wpedantic]

Comment: What about a struct without a union? Assume that I define keyCert as I defined c. Can't I cast a struct in a size of uint32_t to uint32_t?

Comment: @Ofa. No, you cannot. ISO forbids any conversion from/to struct, union, array and matrix, so no matter what is in struct/union, you must read that value, and not convert whole struct to another type. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that this version works:
keyCert temp;
temp.d = pCertHeader->flags;
Now I can use temp.c

Comment: @Ofa. Ok, but keep in mind that your code might be incompatible on some systems/version. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.